# Error when trying to create a LatLngBounds object from valid LatLng objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I'm working with the google maps javascript API and currently I'm trying to create a LatLngBounds object so that I can apply it to my google map based on the locations within an array.

I'm finding the southwestern and northeastern most points, creating LatLng objects from them and then trying to use those to create the LatLangBounds object:

```
centerMap: function (){
    var lowestLatitude = this.locations.reduce(function (carry, nextLocation, index){
            return carry < nextLocation.position.lat && carry !== null ? carry : nextLocation.position.lat;
    }, null);

    var lowestLongitude = this.locations.reduce(function (carry, nextLocation, index){
            return carry < nextLocation.position.lng && carry !== null ? carry : nextLocation.position.lng;
    }, null);

    var highestLatitude = this.locations.reduce(function (carry, nextLocation, index){
            return carry > nextLocation.position.lng && carry !== null ? carry : nextLocation.position.lat;
    }, null);

    var highestLongitude = this.locations.reduce(function (carry, nextLocation, index){
            return carry > nextLocation.position.lng && carry !== null ? carry : nextLocation.position.lng;
    }, null);

    debugger;
    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: lowestLatitude, lng: lowestLongitude});
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: highestLatitude, lng: highestLongitude});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds({sw: southWest, ne: northEast});
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

The error I'm running into is when I create the LatLngBounds instance. I get the error:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

The thing is, the LatLng instances for southWest and northEast are created without an error, so it seems odd that trying to create a bounds from two valid LatLng objects would throw an error.

[image: gif of the error happening]

What am I missing that is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're passing an object to the constructor instead of 2 parameters - have you tried this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

Comment: Aww you were too quick for me! +1!

Comment: Well that was a hell of a facepalm moment! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) the constructor takes two parameters, not an object with two properties.  You'll therefore need something like the following:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,  northEast);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) constructor doesn't (currently) take a [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) as an argument. It requires two **Numbers** representing the latitude and longitude of the geographic coordinates (in that order).  This:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: lowestLatitude, lng: lowestLongitude});
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: highestLatitude, lng: highestLongitude});
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds({sw: southWest, ne: northEast});
```

Should be:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(lowestLatitude, lowestLongitude);
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(highestLatitude, highestLongitude);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wybL294r/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var lowestLatitude = bndsObj.bounds.south;
  var lowestLongitude = bndsObj.bounds.west;
  var highestLatitude = bndsObj.bounds.north;
  var highestLongitude = bndsObj.bounds.east;
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(lowestLatitude, lowestLongitude);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(highestLatitude, highestLongitude);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
// New York City bounds
var bndsObj = {
  "bounds": {
    "south": 40.4960439,
    "west": -74.2557349,
    "north": 40.91525559999999,
    "east": -73.7002721
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```